# Can't insert Data into Database using AJAX JQUERY CODEIGNITER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So i'm trying to post data to the server and insert it into my database but i'm having trouble to do so !

the form

```
   <form name="cart" id="myForm">

    <div class="row">  

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mt-25">
          <h6 class="invoice-to">Bill To</h6>
          <fieldset class="invoice-address form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Fullname" class="form-control" value="Full Name">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="invoice-address form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Wilaya" class="form-control" placeholder="Wilaya">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="invoice-address form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Commune" class="form-control" placeholder="Commune">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="invoice-address form-group">
            <input type="text" name="Adresse" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse">   
          </fieldset>
     </div>

   </div><!--row end-->

  </form><!--row end-->
```

and there you have my ajax request :

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
                var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
                var data = $('#myForm').serialize()
                console.log(data)
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Clientslist/addClientsList',
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){

                        console.log(data)
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('okokok')
                    }



                })
            });
```

My controller :

```
    public function addClientsList(){
        $result = $this->clients_model->add_clients();
        $msg['success'] = false;
        $msg['type'] = 'add';
        if($result){
            $msg['success'] = true;
        }
        echo json_encode($msg);
    }
```

My model

```
public function add_clients(){
        $field = array(
               'NomClient'=>$this->input->post('Fullname'),
               'WilayaClient'=>$this->input->post('Wilaya'),
               'CommuneClient'=>$this->input->post('Commune'),
               'AdresseClient'=>$this->input->post('Adresse'),

            );
        $this->db->insert('Clients', $field);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The error i get in the console:

```
POST http://localhost/CRM/Clientslist/addClientsList 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please note that i did load the model in my Autoload file in config.
Also when i switch my controller function addClientsList() to

```
public function showClientsList(){

        echo json_encode("success");
    }
```

the console successfully login the message "success". So my guess is that something is wrong my controller function call !

please help me out !

Comment: can you see your vaues here= console.log(data)

Comment: @MrKhan yes here they're : "Fullname=Zakaria%20Si%20Chaib&Wilaya=Algiers&Commune=Algiers&Adresse=5%C3%A9me%20groupe%20Batiment%20%22B%22%201%C3%A8re%20%C3%A9tage%20%2C%20place%201er%20MAI%2C%20HLM%2C%2016014%2C%20Algeria&status=1"

Comment: $field = array(
               'NomClient'=>$this->input->post('Fullname'),
               'WilayaClient'=>$this->input->post('Wilaya'),
               'CommuneClient'=>$this->input->post('Commune'),
               'AdresseClient'=>$this->input->post('Adresse'),

            );
ok after this line print_r(field) and see output

Comment: u mean i should add it to the controller?

Comment: yes after the above line which is inside add_clients just print_r($field) and see output

Comment: i did it and i got the alert saying error the only difference though this time i didn't get the : POST http://localhost/CRM/Clientslist/addClientsList 500 (Internal Server Error)
error ! good progress i guess

Comment: kindly add ss of the error and also update your code with the print_r you added as its suppose to just print the values of field

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by ss !

Comment: screen shot  of the code and error

Comment: @MrKhan i just posted the screen in the comments. Note that there's error !

Comment: i dont see print_r($field)  anywhere